Toy Pad Emulator for Lego Dimensions failing to start
raspberry@raspberrypi:~/LD-ToyPad-Emulator $ node index.js
fs.js:119
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/dev/hidg0'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:448:3)
    at new RawTransport (/home/raspberry/LD-ToyPad-Emulator/node_modules/node-ld/dist/transports/raw.js:11:27)
    at new ToyPadEmu (/home/raspberry/LD-ToyPad-Emulator/node_modules/node-ld/dist/lib/ToyPadEmu.js:65:69)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raspberry/LD-ToyPad-Emulator/index.js:24:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
raspberry@raspberrypi:~/LD-ToyPad-Emulator $

Whenever I go to load node index.js I get this response. Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspberry Pi Lite Installed (32 bit) how do I fix this?
This is a link to the project (I’ve followed the steps for single board computer): https://github.com/Berny23/LD-ToyPad-Emulator

Have you tried asking the author of the Lego stuff by opening an issue at https://github.com/Berny23/LD-ToyPad-Emulator/issues?

Just added it. fixed this issue by using an older version of Raspberry PI OS Lite (legacy, bullseye) but the problem is now it doesn’t seem to recognise as the Lego dimensions toypad as the Wii u doesn’t recognise it.

I had this exact problem for agers. instead of using Raspberry Pi Lite I used Debian 11.1 witch fixed the problem.
